# On selected index change should not include first column in datagridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` not to include the first column. The reason for it is when I click to expand the DataGridview the page refreshes causing the DataGridView row to collapse again.

Here is an image of my table. I have circled in red the column I would like to remove from the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` function

[image: Column to remove from select]

Here is my code for the `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.

```cs
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvInventario.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowIndex == gvInventario.SelectedIndex)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvInventario" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  AllowSorting="true" ShowFooter="false" DataKeyNames="componente_id, ubicacion_id"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnSelectedIndexChanged" 
        CellPadding="3"  AllowColumResize="True" onsorting="grdDetails_Sorting" GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">    
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("componente_id") %>');" >
                <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("componente_id") %>" width="9px" border="0" src="../images/plus.gif" alt="" /></a>                       
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="20px" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Min" SortExpression="cantidad_mini">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("cantidad_mini") %>' runat="server" /> 
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantityMin" Text='<%# Eval("cantidad_mini") %>' runat="server" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I would like the first column not to be included in selected index changed.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried adding  for (int i = 1; i < row.Cells.Count; i++){} so the first column is not included However this selected way more all the cells under the row that I selected.